# .net Creating a JSON response by combining custom validator and its class

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, customvalidator, jsonresponse

I am trying to create multiple custom validators that validates different classes and combine them into a JSON response using validation errors and classes.

The JSON response I am trying to achieve is in the following format

```
{
    "meta": {
        "apiVersion": "1.0"
    },
    "data": {
        "customer": {
            "title": "Title",
            "firstName": "FNAME",
            "lastName": "LNAME",
            "email": "EMAIL"
        }    
    },
    "errors": {
        "error": {
            "code": "CODE",
            "message": "MESSAGE",
            "value": "VALUE"
        },
        "customer": {
            // this is dynamic depending on the validation results
            "firstName": {
                "code": "CODE",
                "message": "MESSAGE",
                "value": "VALUE"
            },
            // this is dynamic depending on the validation results
            "LastName": {
                "code": "CODE",
                "message": "MESSAGE",
                "value": "VALUE"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the C# code that I am trying to use is given below:

```
Meta meta = new Meta();
meta.apiVersion =  "1.0";
Errors error2 = new Errors();

RootObject rObject = new RootObject();
Data data = new Data();
Customer cust = new Customer();
cust.title = "Mr";
cust.firstName = "Bob";
cust.lastName = "Joel";
cust.email = "test794@yahoo.com";

data.customer = cust;

rObject.meta = meta;
rObject.data = data;

var context = new ValidationContext(rObject.data.customer, serviceProvider: null, items: null);
var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
var isVALID = Validator.TryValidateObject(rObject.data.customer, 
                                          context, results,
                                          validateAllProperties: true);

if (results.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (var error in results)
    {
        dynamic t = null;

        foreach (var mem in error.MemberNames)
        {
            t = mem.ToString();
        }

        t.message = error.ErrorMessage;
        rObject.errors = t; 
    }
}

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rObject, Formatting.Indented);
```

I am not sure if I am heading in the right direction as the problem I am mainly facing is within the errors object which depends on the ValidationResults. So if there are validation errors I use `foreach` to go though them but the main issue is how to create an object depending on the field name that gave the error and then add error message within that.

So if first name had error I need to create an object called first name and so on.

Comment: You need to better understand what you're trying to do. JSON is just an object, with each property being able to contain whatever types are needed. For example, in your JSON example, you have the "errors" property as an object. That would most likely be better suited as an array. Then inside of there, you could have objects which contain the errors, however it looks like the way you're trying to approach this is too tightly coupled to the structure of your `Customer` type. Your errors should be errors, not customers.

Comment: @krillgar Thanks for your response. I have solved this using a Dictionary code given below. also I agree with you errors should be errors but unfortunately I am not controlling that I just have to spit json in this format hence all the mess
   

Errors errors = new Errors();
Dictionary<string, Error> dic = new Dictionary<string, Error>();